# Server, Client socket implementation

Tags: java, sockets

Am writing a Server, client chat program using Java Socket. Here is my code for the Server socket class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8085);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO Error, " + ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        System.out.println("Listening for incoming connections");
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to accept connection " + ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Connection Successful");
        System.out.println("Listening to get input");
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            System.out.println("Server: ");
            inputLine = input.readLine();
            output.println(inputLine);
            if (!inputLine.equals("exit")) {

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        output.close();
        input.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

The client is able to make a connection and send a message to the server. The server can also receive the messages sent by the client. The problem is that when the message is sent from the server, the client does not receive the message. Here is my client socket code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Client {
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
{
    BufferedReader input;
    PrintStream output;
    BufferedReader clientInput;
    try (Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8085)) {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        output = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
        clientInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        while(true)
        {
            System.out.println("Client: ");
            line = clientInput.readLine();
            output.println("Server: " + line );
            if(line.equals("quit"))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
    clientInput.close();
    output.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Please do share with us how you have attempted to resolve the problem so far.

Comment: There are _many_ questions here on SO about chat in Java using sockets. I [searched](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=chat+java+socket) (in the search box at the top of this page) for `chat java socket` and found hundreds of results.

Comment: @StephenP I'll flag this a duplicate if you provide a link to a specific question which has a similar protocol issue.  Sockets are general and there are many nuances of possible problems programmers encounter with them.  This is an example of a protocol sequence problem.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea I was going to vote to close as a duplicate but I couldn't find (in the short time I had available) an appropriately close question; but I did find many that I thought would be helpful to the OP so I settled for suggesting he search.

Answer (score 2):

Server side:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8085);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IO Error, " + ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        System.out.println("Listening for incoming connections");
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Failed to accept connection " + ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("Connection Successful");
        System.out.println("Listening to get input");
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {

            System.out.println("Client request: " + inputLine);

            String resp = "some response as you need";
            output.println(resp);
            System.out.println("Server response: " + resp);

            if (!inputLine.equals("exit")) {

            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        output.close();
        input.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader input;
        PrintStream output;
        BufferedReader clientInput;
        try (Socket client = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8085)) {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            output = new PrintStream(client.getOutputStream());
            clientInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            while (true) {

                String inputStr = clientInput.readLine();

                output.println(inputStr);
                System.out.println("Client: " + inputStr);

                if (inputStr.equals("quit")) {
                    break;
                }

                String serverResp = input.readLine();
                output.println("Server: " + serverResp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is tested.

Comment: System.in is needed for the OP's design to read the user's commands.  Switching that will also break things.

Comment: This is so simple - so I given just the hints. OK, the working solution follows :)

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to flush your output streams when you are done with them, the info you are sending may have buffered.

Comment: This is not the issue.  The OP identified (correctly) that the messages are getting from client to server and from server to client.  The flushing is happening already on newlines.

Answer (score 0):

The server is expecting an extra line from the client input here:

```
while ((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(inputLine);
    System.out.println("Server: ");
    inputLine = input.readLine(); // <--- here
```

The client is not reading from the **InputStream** called **input** it gets when it connects to the server.  It is only reading the local console input from **clientInput**.

In the while loop in Client.java you need something like this after the quit block to get the server's response:

```
System.out.println("Server: " + input.readLine());
```